# How do you display an array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code which takes three input fields and i store them in an object when i click submit and displays them. But it only displays the current value and not all the value which I've entered into the array of objects.

```
    class Emp1 extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
           obj: {name :'', email: '', age: '', phone: ''},
           items: []
        }
      }

      save(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var obj1 = this.state.obj;
        obj1.name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.field.refs.name1).value;
        obj1.email = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.field.refs.email1).value;
        obj1.age = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.field.refs.age1).value;
        obj1.phone = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.field.refs.phone1).value;
        var arr = [];
        arr.push(obj1)
        this.setState({
          obj: obj1,
          items: arr
        })
      }

      render() {
        return(
        <div>
        <Fields ref="field"  save={this.save.bind(this)}/>
        <Display items={this.state.obj} />
        </div>
      )
      }

    }

    class Fields extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" ref="name1"  /><br/>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" ref="email1"  /><br/>
            <label>Age</label>
            <input type="text" ref="age1"  /><br/>
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" ref="phone1"   /><br/>
            <button type="submit" onClick={ this.props.save }>Submit</button>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    class Display extends React.Component {
      render(){
        return (
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li><b>Name:</b> {this.props.items.name}</li>
              <li><b>Email:</b> {this.props.items.email}</li>
              <li><b>Age:</b> {this.props.items.age}</li>
              <li><b>Phone:</b> {this.props.items.phone}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default Emp1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to display all the form's values that have been sent, you can try what I did.

I changed your state structure, your "save" method and the render method of the class "Emp1" to display every single submitted forms.

```
class Emp1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       items: []
    }
  }

  save(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var obj1 = {};
    obj1.name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.field.refs.name1).value;
    obj1.email = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.field.refs.email1).value;
    obj1.age = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.field.refs.age1).value;
    obj1.phone = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.field.refs.phone1).value;
    var newArr = this.state.items.slice();
    newArr.push(obj1)
    this.setState({
      items: newArr
    })
  }

  render() {
    let displayItems = this.state.items.map((thisForm) => (
      <Display items={thisForm}/>
    ))
    return(
    <div>
      <Fields ref="field"  save={this.save.bind(this)}/>
      {displayItems}
    </div>
  )
  }

}

class Fields extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" ref="name1"  /><br/>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" ref="email1"  /><br/>
        <label>Age</label>
        <input type="text" ref="age1"  /><br/>
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" ref="phone1"   /><br/>
        <button type="submit" onClick={ this.props.save }>Submit</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Display extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><b>Name:</b> {this.props.items.name}</li>
          <li><b>Email:</b> {this.props.items.email}</li>
          <li><b>Age:</b> {this.props.items.age}</li>
          <li><b>Phone:</b> {this.props.items.phone}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This really helped. But what if you want to display it in a table?
I've added a table in the Display component and every time I add a record it displays the table headers as well, for each record.

Comment: You need to wrap the {displayItems} that is in the "Emp1"'s render method inside a <table> tag, like that : <table border="..." style="....">{displayItems}</table>.
And in your "Fields"'s render method you have to return a <tr> tag instead of the <div> and wrap each label/input in <td> to display the data as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

When you write this

```
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(obj1)
    this.setState({
      obj: obj1,
      items: arr
    })
```

You create a new empty array, then reset the state.items with this new array that contains only 1 obj

Try like this

```
    //var arr = [];
    //arr.push(obj1)
    this.setState({
      obj: obj1,
      items: [...this.state.items, obj1] // this will create new array from old with new item
    })
```

Comment: Then you can loop among items array in your Display component

Comment: You don't have to mutate the state.obj also, just write var obj1 = {}

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

to print all values in the array.. you need to iterate over the items array.. 
this is what is missing in the code..

`put the below modification in the render block of 1st component(Emp1)`

`render() {
        let displayElems = this.state.items.map((d) => {
             return <Display items={d} />;
        });
        return(
            <div>
              <Fields ref="field"  save={this.save.bind(this)}/>
              {displayElems}
            </div>
          )
      }`

hope this will work.. 
I just modified your code for simplicity.

you should make some naming change.. e.g. `<Display items={d} />`
here intstead of items - `item` should be used :-)

Comment: Thank you for answering!